# Disable Windows 10 language popup

Tags: windows-10, language, hotkeys, input-languages

Is it possible to disable the popup list of input languages at the bottom right corner when having <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd> pressed in Windows 10 version 1903?

[image]

I do not want to disable the <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd> hotkey
(or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd> for that matter) or the ability to switch languages; I just want to switch off this popup that was introduced in build 1903.

I've tried [turning off the language indicator](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/103041-turn-off-language-bar-input-indicator-windows-10-a.html). 
The indicator turns off, the popup stays.

To add insult to injury, the popup often appears when I'm not even going to change the input language. 
E.g., I'm editing text in a text editor, actively using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> and <kbd>Shift</kbd> to select and move blocks of text, and the language popup keeps appearing.

Comment: @Ramhound I want to disable the list, without removing the languages, ie, be able to switch with Alt+Shift.

Comment: I installed just this version of Windows 10, so, I'm not sure.

Comment: Did anyone find solution for it? Seems to be present only on newly installed Windows 10.

Comment: This issue just appeared on my Windows system after cloning it to the new hard drive. I didn't have it before the migration.

Answer (score 1):

Until we find a solution, I am trying to change language quickly (not press the buttons for too long).

If I am pressing Alt first, I am releashing it quickly after pressing Shift.

If I am pressing Shift first, it doesn't matter how long I keep the buttons pressed - the popup doesn't appear at all.

I hope this helps..!

Comment: Not a solution. An inconvenient workaround at best.

Comment: @AgentFire I clarified it's not a solution at the 5 first words... :P

Answer (score 1):

I used Windows 10 Tweaker (Google it. It's free and you can upgrade to premium if you wish but free does the job well too).

[Select "Preconigure Explorer", then click on "choose" and select "Remove language pop-up..." then click on "Apply".](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jECRN.png)

p.s. Antivirus apps get crazy so don't forget to disable them before downloading and then archive (just in case the antivirus deletes it after the job is done because you might need it). Another thing I encountered was that whenever I hover the mouse over the "Apply" button, tweaker gets closed by itself. I then basically used "Tab" or/and "Shift + Tab" for going forward and backwards and "Space" for selecting and "Enter" for applying.
Be careful with the other functions of the tweaker as you might brick your Windows.

EDIT: This worked on Windows 11 Pre-release but doesn't work on the released version of Windows 11.

Answer (score 1):

You need to patch `C:\Windows\System32\InputSwitch.dll` using hex editor like [HxD](https://mh-nexus.de/en/hxd/).

Just look for `74 1F 48 63 DD` and replace first byte (`74`) to `EB`.

To replace the file with the patched one, you will need to:

1. Disable Windows Defender
2. Put the modified `InputSwitch.dll` file with a changed name, for example `InputSwitch_new.dll`.
3. Assign ownership of `InputSwitch.dll` file to current admin user
4. Open `cmd.exe` and change directory `cd C:\Windows\System32`
5. Close processes: `taskkill /f /im explorer.exe` and `taskkill /f /im TextInputHost.exe`
6. Rename original file: `ren InputSwitch.dll InputSwitch.dll.bak`
7. Rename new file: `ren InputSwitch_new.dll InputSwitch.dll`
8. Run explorer: `start explorer`
9. Remove write permissions for all users except TrustedInstaller
10. Set ownership back to `NT Service\TrustedInstaller`.
11. Reboot OS

---

[Win10Tweaker](https://win10tweaker.ru/) is also a good option, but I am not sure if it applies exactly the patch method and not just replacing a DLL with an unknown version (this could cause compatibility problems on your OS version).